# Is it common to pray to know if the Catholic Church is true?

Tags: catholicism, catholic-catechism

I'm LDS and I'm wondering if it common for Catholics to pray to know their Church is true? Or is it much more common to find historical, theological, and scriptural proofs for belief?

Comment: I wonder whether a better form of the question is which of those are encouraged by the church? This would take it out of the realm of what people actually do into the realm of what is the official position?

Comment: I think this question is too broad and should be closed or improved. What do you mean if their Church is true? True religion? Christian faith? True with their teaching, historicity or certain parts? Maybe only certain teachings. Some people might not believe in some of the doctrines but be OK with others. The church leaders themselves prays for wisdom when defining the teaching and dogmas...

Comment: @grasper, I think "True" in this case means what G.K. Chesterton meant when he asked why he entered the Catholic Church: "Because it is true"

Comment: I get, by web search, that the term "true church" means *one* true church to LDS (as in https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/general-conference/1985/10/the-only-true-church?lang=eng). Is that what you mean here?

Comment: I think it is a good question, there is space for answers to link to Catholic doctrine/articles encouraging this type of prayer if it is indeed common. In the absence of such doctrine (which I'm almost certain will be the case) since it is 'hard to prove a negative' like this, answerers can share their experience of being practicing Catholics and such an approach to prayer being uncommon in their communities.

Comment: Simple answer: No, you need to believe the Roman Catholic Church is true and not to know. The faith or believe is essential for your salvation. You will only KNOW after you die. However, you can still pray to deepen your faith...

Answer (score 5):

**Is it common to pray to know if the Catholic Church is true?**

> And I say to thee: That thou art Peter; and upon this rock I will build my church, and the gates of hell shall not prevail against it. - [Matthew 16:18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2016%3A18&version=DRA)

To my knowledge it is not common for practicing Catholics to pray to know if the Catholic Church is true!

For so-called Catholics in name only or those who simply are very irreligious in their lifestyle, may not even care one way or another. This same set of principles would be true in all other Christian denominations.

Genuine doubts about the faith or in the Church, could very much strengthen a soul’s unity towards God. Everyone has doubts about something.

How common to pray to know if the Catholic Church is true is actually unknown. No one has ever brought this up to me, but I am sure it happens.

This reminds me of the words of St. Paul:

> 7 I have fought a good fight, I have finished my course, I have kept the faith.
>
> 8 As to the rest, there is laid up for me a crown of justice, which the Lord the just judge will render to me in that day: and not only to me, but to them also that love his coming. Make haste to come to me quickly. - [2 Timothy 4:7-8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Timothy%204%3A7-8&version=DRA)

The ***dark night of the soul*** can effect one on any number of points of one’s faith. As long as intellectual assent is not given there is no sin involved and the Devil loses.

> [**Dark Night of the Soul**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Night_of_the_Soul) is a poem written by the 16th-century Spanish mystic and poet St. John of the Cross. The author himself did not give any title to his poem, on which he wrote two book-length commentaries: Ascent of Mount Carmel (Subida del Monte Carmelo) and The Dark Night (Noche Oscura).
>
> **In Roman Catholic spirituality**
>
> The term "dark night (of the soul)" in Roman Catholic spirituality describes a spiritual crisis in the journey toward union with God, like that described by St. John of the Cross.
>
> St. Thérèse of the Child Jesus and the Holy Face, OCD, a 19th-century French nun and doctor of the Church, wrote of her own experience of the dark night. Her dark night derived from doubt of the existence of eternity, to which doubt she nonetheless did not give intellectual or volitional assent, but rather prevailed by a deepening of her Catholic faith. However, she painfully suffered through this prolonged period of spiritual darkness, even declaring to her fellow nuns: "If you only knew what darkness I am plunged into".

While this spiritual crisis is usually temporary, it may endure for a long time. The "dark night" of St. Paul of the Cross in the 18th century endured 45 years, from which he ultimately recovered. The dark night of St. Teresa of Calcutta, whose own name in religion she selected in honor of St. Thérèse, "may be the most extensive such case on record", having endured from 1948 almost until her death in 1997, with only brief interludes of relief, according to her letters.

On the other end of the spectrum, converts to the Catholic Church, most certainly pray to know if the Catholic Church is the true Church.

Comment: For me I know its a combination of prayer and rational thought. Prayer is for me to make sure I'm following God and not my own desires through my journey. But to abandon rationality and evidence for pure prayer would be foolish, since it is only through prayer and rationality in the first place that I have any evidence that prayer is reliable!

Comment: @LukeHill Indeed, we are to reason from the Scriptures.

Comment: I don't think including "dark night" experiences is relevant to the question, since the saints who experience it don't doubt that the Catholic church is true, nor doubt that the doctrines are true, or do they?  Do they really experience intellectual doubt of the correctness of doctrines or the truthfulness of the church?  Isn't it a matter of feeling the absence of God?  I don't think the Catholic church teaches that feeling of closeness of God to be proof of correctness of doctrines, but rather an aid to spiritual growth.

Answer (score 5):

I am someone who has had many conversations with LDS evangelists. I take it that this question refers to something often said by such evangelists when those they talk to express doubts about the truth of LDS doctrine: "Just pray about it to see if this is the truth or not."

In similar conversations Catholics and most Christians tend not to say things like that. There are a number of reasons for that. Most such conversations are with people who don't believe in God at all. They are not usually open to letting prayer decide the matter. (Why would they if they are uncertain of God's existence?). Such people are also extremely inexperienced in the matter of prayer, and can end up with the wrong conclusion.

Also praying to God to ask about matters of fact is fraught with danger. It may sound like a good idea (God knows the truth, so obviously he would tell you if you asked him) but in practice it doesn't work like that. Otherwise Christians would simply pray for the answers to their mathematics tests and get full marks. God expects us to use other faculties he has given us. Answers like this are considered the "gift of knowledge" which is one of the gifts of the Spirit, given as God wills  and hence not automatically available to all Christians, let alone those who don't believe.

Also most Christians are convinced of the rationality of their reasons for believing in God. Resorting to "just pray about it" would seem to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

As a Catholic, I can say that it is common, and laudable to pray for the people guiding the church.

Pinpointing an official position is hard since it's kind of navel-gazey, but praying for the Pope (or at least the [Pope's intentions](https://onepeterfive.com/pray-pray-intentions-holy-father/)) is a requirement for a Plenary Indulgence; so the church does intend for the faithful to pray for its leaders.

Personally, taking some of the Church leaders who I liked a lot, but proved to be very poor examples. I think it's very important to pray that *they* will be true to the Church, because people certainly have the capacity to fall off the wagon. And when that happens it causes scandal and causes people to doubt the veracity of the Church.

---

As for the way someone gets to figuring out that the Catholic Church in particular is true, G.K. Chesterton puts it best

> But this involved accuracy of the thing makes it very difficult to do what I now have to do, to describe this accumulation of truth. It is very hard for a man to defend anything of which he is entirely convinced. It is comparatively easy when he is only partially convinced. He is partially convinced because he has found this or that proof of the thing, and he can expound it. But a man is not really convinced of a philosophic theory when he finds that something proves it. He is only really convinced when he finds that everything proves it. And the more converging reasons he finds pointing to this conviction, the more bewildered he is if asked suddenly to sum them up. Thus, if one asked an ordinary intelligent man, on the spur of the moment, "Why do you prefer civilization to savagery?" he would look wildly round at object after object, and would only be able to answer vaguely, "Why, there is that bookcase . . . and the coals in the coal-scuttle . . . and pianos . . . and policemen." The whole case for civilization is that the case for it is complex. It has done so many things. But that very multiplicity of proof which ought to make reply overwhelming makes reply impossible.

> G.K. Chesterton - Orthodoxy - Chapter 6

He noted a number of incidental things.  But his main supposition that the Church was not only the True Church, but a Truth Telling Church.

> I have another far more solid and central ground for submitting to it as a faith, instead of merely picking up hints from it as a scheme. And that is this: that the Christian Church in its practical relation to my soul is a living teacher, not a dead one. It not only certainly taught me yesterday, but will almost certainly teach me to-morrow. Once I saw suddenly the meaning of the shape of the cross; some day I may see suddenly the meaning of the shape of the mitre. One fine morning I saw why windows were pointed; some fine morning I may see why priests were shaven. Plato has told you a truth; but Plato is dead. Shakespeare has startled you with an image; but Shakespeare will not startle you with any more. But imagine what it would be to live with such men still living, to know that Plato might break out with an original lecture to-morrow, or that at any moment Shakespeare might shatter everything with a single song. The man who lives in contact with what he believes to be a living Church is a man always expecting to meet Plato and Shakespeare to-morrow at breakfast. He is always expecting to see some truth that he has never seen before.

In fact it all boils down to the Church *being* true:

> The difficulty of explaining "why I am a Catholic" is that there are ten thousand reasons all amounting to one reason: that Catholicism is true.

> Why I Am Catholic - G.K. Chesterton

So more important than praying *that* the Church is true, is praying that one *sees* the truths of Jesus that the Church proclaims.

Comment: "So more important than praying that the Church is true, is praying that one sees the truths of Jesus that the Church proclaims." As imperfect as they are. +1

Comment: When I read this, I wonder why people tend to compare LDS to protestants and not catholics.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how common it is for Catholics *themselves* to pray for knowledge as to whether Catholicism is true; however, it seems reasonable enough for non-Catholics to do so. If a Christian is engaged in any kind of intellectual exercise, why shouldn't they pray for help in discovering the truth? That seems like a perfectly rational thing to do.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Comment: Who would the non-catholics pray to? Allah, Budha, Krishna? Such prayer wouldn't make sense. Praying to God weather he exits or approves of certain religion might be an act of doubt and not a prayer.

Comment: @Grasper - How about Prostestants and Eastern Orthodox Christians? How about Jews? Even Muslims at direct their worship to the God of Abraham, although we think that they are doing so in an incorrect manner. It seems that there are many, many people who might be able to sincerely pray to the Abrahamic God to know whether a certain faith is true.

Comment: Often a 'certain faith' is confused with a 'particular denomination'. The OP belongs to the LDS denomination which has a strong emphasis for praying to know 'a burning in the bosom' as confirmation of praying to know if the LDS is 'the true faith'. The OP seeks to know if Catholics do similarly. 'The God of Abraham' in Christianity is also claimed as being the God of Jews and Muslims, but the OP is not asking about them. Within the Christian religion, does the Catholic denomination urge prayer for confirmation that IT is the true church (as in the only true church)? Can you answer that?

Comment: @Anne, the Catholics don't need to pray for it. The church already answered that in one of their doctrine. "There is no salvation outside of the Catholic Church". Again, if they were to "pray" to prove the church is true, that wouldn't be a prayer but an act of doubt. The prayer manifests only if you have faith. Knowing is not part of faith. You can't know 100% otherwise you would exclude faith but faith is necessary for your salvation.

Comment: @Grasper  My comments are based on what I know of the point of view of the LDS denomination which the OP is). I had noted the other answers explaining what you said so there was no need to repeat any of that. What JDClayworth said (as a Catholic) is an excellent answer, as is Ken Graham's. That is why I did not answer, as existing answers answer fully, and that's why I asked Geach's Bulldog that question in my comment to him.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience there is no suggestion by the Church for members to pray to know if the Church is true as some kind of general rule. This is also the case in my non-denominational Christian experience.

Now for wavering Catholics, or anyone wavering in faith matters, it is unknowable how they commonly resolve the problem. Statistics are not kept.

I'm going to second one thing from one of the other answers, praying for explicit answers to explicit questions is risky.

Having said that, if I were myself wavering in a matter of Christian faith, I would do 2 things: Pray to the God of the Bible to draw me closer, and increase my time within the scriptures of the Bible.

Answer (score 1):

I live in India, a country which has only 2.3 % of the people following Christianity-- all denominations put together. Not even a single Non-Christian, in my entire life, prompted me to re-examine my  faith and to find out if the Catholic Church is true. But then, I have come across Non-catholic Christians of various denominations, including two young men from Idaho, US who did ask me to have an introspection , which I politely refused.